# CodeIgniter implement search bar functionality

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search

I'm trying create a search functionality to search in my database for the following information (Destination,Departure, dateOfDestination,dateOfDeparture,price,details)

I've created a search function in my model and controller, and my search bar in home page (as you can see from picture), but I don't know where to list a result and how can make the search bar work correctly. I believe I have to use JavaScript for that.  Does anyone have any pointer or suggestions?

[image: Home Page Search]

**Model**

```
public function search($keyword){
    $this->db->like('mjestoPolaska',$keyword);
    $query = $this->db->get('posts');
    return $query->result();
}
```

**Controller**

```
 public function search_keyword(){
        $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
        $data['results'] = $this->Posts_model->search($keyword);
        $this->load->view('result_view', $data);
    }
```

**View**

```
<table>
<?php foreach($results as $row){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->mjestoPolaska?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->mjestoOdredista?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->datumPolaska?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->datumPovratka?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->cijena?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->opis?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Try to google it. You'll get examples.

Comment: A general idea for how this might work is when someone types a search, use JavaScript AJAX to submit a request to your controller with the search parameter being the user's query, then in your javascript use the response from your controller to display the results (assuming you want a drop-down search), otherwise you could probably accomplish this with a standard form!

Comment: The problem is How to display data after searching ? 
And how implement function for searching in JS that search box work clear

Comment: Yuo get data back from your controller, find a way to display that to a user, you could have a a box that's normally hidden, fill the contents of the box with the response html then show it, for example.

Comment: @zack6849 Thank you for giving me idea :)  
I will try this, i like it

Comment: @zack6849 what about using DataTable JQuery ? Is it good solution or not ?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with implementing an ajax search bar from scratch, but datatable, as the name implies, is primarily for displaying tables, are you trying to show a list of flights or something, or just a result page with the table on it?

Comment: @xerror `Destination,Departure, dateOfDestination,dateOfDeparture,price,details` all these search under one table ?? or ? (if  more than one post count)

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Yeah, all of this attributes

Comment: @zack6849 I am createing application Car Sharing, so whatever I only need to implement search doesnt matter in which way

Comment: Google select2; probably does what you need